# PHP page not posting and if statement is broken

Tags: php, post, if-statement, submit

```
<?php
            $srver = $_GET['S'];
            $fnum = $_GET['F'];
            if ($srver == '')($connect = odbc_connect('van' ,'user' , 'password'));
            if ($srver == '')   {$other_srvr = 'T' ; $other = 'Toronto';}
            if ($srver == 'V') ($connect = odbc_connect('van' ,'user' , 'password'));
            if ($srver == 'V')  {$other_srvr = 'T' ; $other = 'Toronto';}
            if ($srver == 'T') ($connect = odbc_connect("tor" ,"user" , "password"));
            if ($srver == 'T')  {$other_srvr = 'V' ; $other = 'Vancouver';}
            if ($fnum == '')    {$Fnumber = '&F=' ;}
            echo "<form method='post' action=$PHP_SELF> ";
            echo "<a href='mypage.php?S=$other_srvr$Fnumber'>Change Server to $other</a>" ;
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<strong> Filter Number : </strong><input name='F' type='text' size='20'>";
            echo" <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Search' />"; # Create submit button
            echo "</form>"; 
            $sum = array();
            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
                    {

                        $r = "1" ; 
                    }
            else
                    {                   

                    $query = Select abc from table;

                    }

                    odbc_close($connect);
?>
```

So this is my code. The problem is how do i get the page to submit it just refreshes. Can someone please explain and secondly i am checking for server with if statements on top, is there to way to do that in single line. I cant seem to find it to work.

Thanks

Comment: do you literally just have some random SQL outside of a string there?

Comment: `$PHP_SELF` is not a thing either. you should generally use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, or just leave the action blank. it will post back to itself by default. also, put your html attribute in double-quotes. single quotes aren't valid, even if they are supported.

Comment: ya its a long SQL so i didnt want to post 40 additional lines here.

Comment: @OP: well, with all the other errors in there, I don't know which parts are pseudo-code and which parts are real. should make it more clear ;)

Comment: So the problem is how do i write if statement for server selection so that i dont have to write multiple lines for single if statement. Secondly my page doesnt post anything, it just refreshes where as i want to enter something in inputbox n use that in query and also update the url with variable like mypage.php?S=$server&F=12345

Comment: Without trying to sound mean please go and learn some basic syntax before posting. And don't combine questions - generally they should be separated into different problems for others who might find the answers useful.

Comment: @alfo I appreciate your help sir and i dont think ur comment is mean, but i would love to learn the syntax but i couldnt grasp it from w3cschool thats why i posted here. Moving forward ill try my best to break down problems so others can find it useful as well. Thanks

Comment: @user1467788: your question hardly makes sense. You can put as many statements as you like inside of an `if` block (between the curly braces). Don't try to combine multiple assignments in to one. Your page isn't refreshing, it's posting back to itself, assuming you haven't butchered that "action" attribute too badly. You just aren't doing anything with the results. All you've done is set this random `$r` variable to one, and ... that's it. It re-renders the page as normal.

Comment: Side note: You should turn off register globals `$PHP_SELF` [Why?](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php)

Comment: http://www.w3fools.com strikes again

Comment: I'm not insulting you. I'm insulting W3Schools. My point was you mentioned http://www.w3schools.com as a reference and that site is full of misinformation. Check out http://www.w3fools.com to learn about the inaccuracies and settle down.

Comment: @AlienWebguy My apologies but your post was more of a pseudo post if you know what i mean ;)

Comment: I don't know what you mean. You are a confusing person.

Answer (score 1):

First off, if $PHP_SELF somehow worked, it's not in "". Second, you need to look up how use SQL with PHP. Something like this maybe?

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT abc FROM table");
```

Comment: sql is working fine i just posted pseudo code for reading ease. $PHP_SELF is echoed out so shouldnt it be in "".

Comment: Without badgering, this is the point where someone says please don't use mysql_* functions, use PDO or mysqli instead.

Comment: @user1467788: Not to be a pain in the behind, but if you paste pseudo-code and ask what is the problem with the pages (real) code, A lot of people will be misguided into fixing you pseudo-code.. You can "strip down" the code if you want to make it more readable, but pasting pseudo-code will just start a wild-goose chase to fix the error..

Comment: @Raidenace My apologies, i am a newbie to this site, slowly grasping the fundamentals of asking question.

Comment: @user1467788: Don't apologize, actually your questions are way better than some I asked when I first came to this site! :P Welcome aboard! BTW, is the original question, completely non-pseudo-code now?

Comment: Ok let break it down for you

Q1 - if ($srver == '')($connect = odbc_connect('van' ,'user' , 'password'));
            if ($srver == '')   {$other_srvr = 'T' ; $other = 'Toronto';}   How do i concatenate these lines ?

Q2 How do i make the page post to itself with Inputbox variable n server so that it works. form submit isnt working for me. If you could help that will be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

`if ($srver == '')($connect =` should be `if ($srver == ''){$connect =...` and so on, curly braces and whatnot.

Comment: I tried but it doesnt work with curly braces

 if ($srver == '')($connect = odbc_connect('van' ,'user' , 'password'));  

the first line itself has round braces inside round braces.

Comment: What..? It would be this: `if($srver == ''){$connect = odbc_connect('van' ,'user' , 'password');}`